# spot.im not loading comment section with ionic v1

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to load spot.im comment section in ionic v1 app using below script

```
<script async src="https://recirculation.spot.im/spot/<my-spot-id>"></script><div data-spotim-module="recirculation" data-spot-id="<my-spot-id>"></div><script async data-spotim-module="spotim-launcher" src="https://launcher.spot.im/spot/<my-spot-id>" data-post-id="<my-post-id>"></script>
```

but not working in ionic but i tried in cordova that is working fine. Might some issue with angularJS.

I am getting error in ionic http://prntscr.com/g9mouw

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the network requests are failing. Did whitelist the spot.im domain and subdomains?

A tutorial for whitelisting domains on ionic:

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/05/whitelist-external-resources-for-use-in-ionic-framework/